# c printing string syntax

Tags: c, arrays, string

Just stuck on c syntax regarding strings.

Say I have a string like (`name[5]="peter";`) in c say if I just wanted to print the last character of string or check the last character of the string, which in this case would be `'r'` how can I do this?

The way I was thinking does not seem to work

```
name[5]="peter";
if(name[5]=="r") printf("last character of name is r");
```

Question: is there some sort of function to do this that can check one character of array, is a certain value, like name[5] is 'r' in string peter or likewise name[1] is 'n'

Also how do I use printf to print that certain char, having problems using

```
printf("last character of name is %s",name[5]) ???
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing, strings are null-terminated. For a five-character string you need to allocate a 6-character array to handle the `'\0'` character at the end of the string.

```
char name[6] = "peter";
// peter is {'p', 'e', 't', 'e', 'r', '\0'}
```

To check what individual characters are, index the string using square brackets. The first character is index 0, the second is index 1, etc. Also, C makes a distinction between strings and individual characters. A string is written with `"double quotes"`. Characters are written with single quotes: `'r'`.

```
if (name[4] == 'r') {
    printf("fifth character of name is r\n");
}
```

To find the last character you need to know the length of the string. If you know the length ahead of time you can hard code it; otherwise, use the `strlen` function to calculate the string length. And then subtract 1 because indexes are 0-based.

```
if (name[strlen(name) - 1] == 'r') {
    printf("last  character of name is r\n");
}
```

To print individual characters with `printf` you can use the `%c` format specifier. `%c` prints a single character.

```
printf("fifth character of name is %c\n", name[4]);
printf("last  character of name is %c\n", name[strlen(name) - 1]);
```

Comment: thanks, so is the NULL character present in all strings even in command line arguments like argv[]. Does strlen() count the \0 character or do you have to put +1 at end?

Comment: Yes, the null terminator is present in all strings. Without it you wouldn't know how long a string is because there is no length field. `strlen` does not count the `'\0'`, only the "real" characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
char *s = "peter";
char lastChar = s[strlen(s) - 1];
printf("last character in s is %c\n", lastChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that strings in C are null-terminated. That means that they end in the `'\0'` character.  You  have to save space for that.  Moreover, arrays are indexed from `0`, so `name[5]` specifies a string with 4 characters and a null character, with the null character at index 4 of `name`.

You need to fix these:

```
char name[6]="peter";
```

so now:

```
name[0] = 'p'
name[1] = 'e'
...
name[4] = 'r'
name[5] = 0
```

So your `if` statement should use index 4, not 5:

```
if(name[4]=="r") printf("last character of name is r");
```

Finally, to print a single char, use th `%c` modifier, not `%s`.  Your final `printf` should read:

printf("last character of name is %c",name[4])

Otherwise you're printing a string that *begins* from the offset you specified, which (if you allocated enough space in your string) will be `'\0'`, which is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two big issues here:

- First is the **length** of the string
- Second is the **index** of the string.

### Length

In C, strings are NULL-terminated, meaning they have an invisible `\0` at the end to mark the end of the string. You have to account for this invisible charater, so while `peter` is only 5 letters, you need one more space for the Null-terminator.

```
char name[6]="peter";  /* implied \0 at the end of the string */
```

---

### Index

In C, strings and arrays are 0-indexed, meaning that the first element is [0].
In the case of your string, the indexes are:

```
[0] `p`
[1] `e`
[2] `t`
[3] `e`
[4] `r`
[5] `\0`
```

So where you expect `r` to be the 5th character, it is at index **4**.

If you declare the string properly (with 6 elements instead of 5), and look at index [4], you'll find that is is `r` as expected.